# SQL Multiple return values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, Test with one column, ItemNo as an integer. I want to count the number of equal ItemNo's. Getting the count one at a time is easy:

```
SELECT COUNT(ItemNo) FROM Test WHERE ItemNo=1;
```

which returns 3.
How can I have all results (in an array or similar) in one go?

The table Test with the ItemNo column:

```
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
3
4
4
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ItemNo,Count(*)as cntt
FROM your_table
GROUP BY ItemNo
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select ItemNo, count(1) from Test group by ItemNo;
```